# Joomla 1.6 multilingual function dont change template

Tags: joomla

everyone knows that joomla 1.6/1.7 have native multilang feature , so im try to use different template for different langs for some reasons.

I were installed 2 templates and set 1 of them for all languages( the joomla dont get me any other choice , i just can select all ) , and one of them set to fa-IR.

after that i were activated the language filter plugin.

i can change the lang variable in get method between "fa" and "en" but i just can see the en template.

anyone know whats the problem?

Comment: Did you try assigning each menu item to adequate template in J1.7 "Template Manager"?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla does not natively allow you to set different templates per language. WooDzu's suggestion is the standard way of achieving the same result, by assigning templates per menu item, where each menu item also has a particular language assigned to it. If that approach isn't working, then it's likely that your templates are a bit non-standard [are they using a particular framework like T3?], or there may be a bug in Joomla.

A more direct way of approaching the problem is using [Chameleon](http://www.metamodpro.com/chameleon/chameleon), which does exactly what you were asking for: it detects the language then sets the template based on that.

Comment: I should note: Chameleon works on Joomla 1.5 or 1.7, not 1.6. If you're still using 1.6 you should upgrade anyway.