# Can I have different templates for different languages in a Joomla multilanguage website?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla3.1

I am creating a multilanguage website (english and italian) and I need have a specific template for the english language and another different one for the italian lainguage.

**Can I have different templates for different languages in a Joomla multilanguage website?**

some hints?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in another post regarding the same problem:

[Joomla 1.6 multilingual function dont change template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189432/joomla-1-6-multilingual-function-dont-change-template)

It is not natively possible to do this.

You can however use Chameleon which allows you set set a template for each language and is compatible with Joomla 2.5 and 3.x

http://www.metamodpro.com/chameleon/chameleon

Hope this helps

Comment: This is not true, this seems to be a not well documented function in the Joomla Docs (I find a valid and clear solution only on the italian Joomla comunity docs section). If you want to use a template for each language, instead of defining for each menu item a different style template, you can assign a global template for each language template Management in the following simple way:
1) Select a template, which is not the default for the site, and parameter Default select a language (I think that Default is the right name of parameter but I am not sure because I have translate it)
1)

Comment: 2) Now you have a default template but for example you can have a specific template for all the language that are not the defaul language (so if the default language is english in this way you can use a different specific templates for italian and french)

Comment: Here the link to the italian doc: http://www.joomla.it/mediawiki/index.php/Joomla!_2.5:Gestione_multilingua
I think that sometimes the official Joomla documentation is a bit confused...

Comment: @AndreaNobili - ahh I was not aware of this at all. Have not seen any English docs regarding it. thanks for pointing it out. You should post it as an proper answer

Comment: Unfortunately, the official documentation of Joomla seems to be very confusing and out of date as well as the answers given by the official community are often not extensive. This is a real shame because Joomla is a great CMS (friendly but powerful and flexible). Often Iprefer to use WordPress (that is less flexible) because its documentation is GREAT and its user comunity is very competent

Comment: the Joomla Docs were updated majorly by the developer I work with. It would seem though that some pages were missed out or still incomplete